# ajax update mysql field without refreshing page

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to get my announce box that has a X button on the top right, to be clicked and it remove the message, and update a mysql query field without refreshing the page

HTML

```
<form id="myForm" action="delanno.php" method="post">
    <div class='announce-box'>
     <div class='announce-message'>$show_message</div>
      <div class='announce-delete'>
       <a class='deleter'>
        <button type='submit' id='sub' name='$show_id' style='height:35px; width:40px'>
         <img src='../css/images/delete_25.png' width='25' height='25'>
        </button>
       </a>
     </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

php (delanno.php)

```
<?php
include("conn.php");

foreach($_POST as $name => $content) { // Most people refer to $key => $value

     $something = "$name"; //ignore this, i did this for testing purposes
     $query = mysql_query("UPDATE announce SET active='disabled' WHERE id='$something' ") or die(mysql_error());
} 

?>
```

ajax // This is supposed to update the php field without refreshing or sending to another page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#sub").click( function() {
     $.post( $("#myForm").attr("action"),
        $("#myForm :input").serializeArray(),
        function(info){ $("#result").html(info);
           });
        });

        $("#myForm").submit( function() {
          return false;
        });
</script>
```

more ajax // this is supposed to remove the announce div when the delete button is clicked.

```
<script>
$('.deleter').on('click', function(){
  $(this).closest('.announce-box').remove();

 })
</script>
```

if i remove

> return false

it sends it to the php page and it obviously works. i'm not sure what to do from here

EDIT: The script doesn't work unless it's being sent to the php page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript selecting DOM elements should be inside a [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function when the DOM is actually ready, e.g.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // $('#some-id') .. etc
});
```

### .

I just searched SO for a duplicate, I think it's out there but I didn't find it, so just posting as an answer and if someone else does, just flag it.